# Use one dynamoDB table with two different serveless app

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-dynamodb, yaml, serverless-framework

I have starting work on DynamoDB, Lambda function and serverless framework.

I have some knowledge of this all and still learning on this.

Now my point is that I crated one serverless app and deploy into AWS. In this app, I have created like 40+ endpoints(Lambda functions) and 4 dynamoDB tables like A, B, C, D.

Now I need to create another separate serverless app and I want to use dynamoDB table A into this app which I created into the previous serverless app.

Is it possible or not? If possible then how can I implement this.

I already try to scan operation into this new app but throughs error like

`2018-06-07T11:02:19.352Z    3e8b6b27-6a42-11e8-acf9-7f86fa9df706    { AccessDeniedException: User: arn:aws:sts::XXXXXXX:assumed-role/serverless-rest-api-dev-us-east-1-lambdaRole/serverless-rest-api-dev-todoList is not authorized to perform: dynamodb:Scan on resource: arn:aws:dynamodb:us-east-1:XXXXXX:table/A`

Here i need to define anything else related to dynamoDB table A into my new `serverless.yml`?

Please help me here if anyone is found the solution for this. Thanks in advance

Comment: Did you set any IAMRoleStatements in your serverless.yml. They give the Lambda function to access the AWS Resources.

Comment: Yes, i have IAMRoleStatements in my serverless.yml file.

Comment: Can you please tell me how can i add into my serverless.yml file?

Answer (score 1):

I got the solution of my problem.

First, I need to check ARN of `table A` into AWS dynamoDB table section which i created into my first application.

Now add that ARN into second serverless application's serverless.yml file's Resource section.

Suppose my ARN of table A is like `arn:aws:dynamodb:us-east-1:XXXXXX:table/todo-task`

Now I need to add this ARN into my second app's serverless.yml file's Resource section. it's like

```
IAMRoleStatement
     - Effect: Allow
           Action:
                - dynamodb:*
           Resource:
                - arn:aws:dynamodb:us-east-1:XXXXXX:table/todo-task
```

Comment: If the dynamo table was created with cloudformation template in your first app's serverless.yml and if you dont have a DeletionPolicy:Retain on it, then if your first stack goes away so does your tables are. Your second app doesnt own that table. Only your fist app does. Keep that in mind :)

Answer (score 0):

If both applications and dynamoDB tables are located in same region it is possible. You should set a corresponding role for the second application to have access to Dynamo DB table. Please check permissions of role :
serverless-rest-api-dev-us-east-1-lambdaRole/serverless-rest-api-dev-todoList

Comment: Thanks for your answer.
Yes, I have both applications and dynamoDB into the same region.
I want to know that I need to 
1) add role into the IAMRoleStatements right?
2) Do I need to add permission role into my first app in which I created dynamoDB table A. right?
3) Can you please help me how can I write that permission for the second app.? I mean just mention that line what I need to add to my 1st application.